# The shortest way of modifying attributes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing this:

```
$("td.myTD").each( function(){
    var rowspan = $(this).attr("rowspan");
    rowspan = parseInt(rowspan) + 1;
    $(this).attr("rowspan", rowspan);                            
});
```

(incrementing by one the rowspan for all the td with class myTD). Is there a shorter way of writing it?

In a perfect world I would like to write soemething like this:

```
$("td.myTD").attr("rowspan", someMagicHereToGetTheAttrValueForEachFoundElement() + 1);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: The `.attr()` method does support a way to do what you are asking, as shown in the answers below, but note that even if it didn't you could shorten the code by eliminating the `rowspan` variable and using the unary plus operator instead of `parseInt()`: `$(this).attr("rowspan", +$(this).attr("rowspan") + 1)` - of course, you'd still need the `.each()` that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.attr()` can take a function that returns the new value from the old one:

```
$("td.myTD").attr("rowspan", function(i, old) { return +old+1 });
```

[DOCUMENTATION](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr)

Comment: Note that it'll need to be `return +old + 1` to convert `old` to a number before doing the addition. (Or you could use `parseInt()` like in the question, but the OP did ask for the shortest.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks. Went with `+old` to distinguish my answer from Palash's.

Comment: Palash's answer was of course correct too, but I voted for yours on the basis that you gave a bit of explanation as to why the code would work.

Answer (score 14):

You can do this using the `.attr( attributeName, function(index, attr) )`:

```
$("td.myTD").attr("rowspan", function(index, attr){
    return parseInt(attr, 10) + 1;
});
```

Here, the above code uses a function which takes the index position of the element in the set and the old attribute value as arguments. And then the  function returns a new attribute value based on the old attribute. This use of a function to compute attribute values is particularly useful when modifying the attributes of multiple elements at once.

For more information, see the [attr function(index, attr) documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr).

Comment: i guess this is the best answer